# Роутинг node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, apt-get

Доброго времени суток. пишу сайт вопреки node js. И в главном файле у меня есть два роутера app get

```
  app.get('/:actReg',function(req, res, next) {
  pid = req.originalUrl.substring(15, 30);
  req.session.linkPass=pid;

    someq.pool.query('UPDATE Users SET Active ="'+ 1 +'" WHERE Email="'+ rows[0].email +'"', function (err, rows, field) {
    });
    if (rows.length > 0) {
      newForm = '<div>' +
          '<p id="bad_pass1" style="color: green">'+'Ваша активація пройшла успішно'+'</p>' +
          '</div>';
    }
    else {
      newForm = 'Посилання не дійсне'
    }
    res.f=newForm;
    next()
  });

});
var lang = require('./bin/langKey.js');
app.get('/:actReg', function(req, res, next)
{
  languageSess = lang.funcLang(req.session.lang, 'missPassword');
  languageSess.text_1 = res.f;
  languageSess.title = 'a3boot';
  var men = menu.rightSide(req,res,next, languageSess);
  languageSess.menu = men;
  res.render('missPassword', languageSess)

});




app.get('/:missPass',function(req, res, next) {

  pid = req.originalUrl.substring(10, 25);
  req.session.linkPass=pid;
  someq.pool.query('Select * From missPassword WHERE link ="' + pid + '"', function (err, rows, field) {

    if (rows.length > 0) {
      newForm =
          '<p id="bad_pass1" style="color: red"></p>'

    }
    else {
      newForm = 'Посилання не дійсне'
    }
    res.f=newForm;
    next()
  });

});

  app.get('/:missPass', function(req, res, next)
  {
    languageSess = lang.funcLang(req.session.lang, 'contacts');
    languageSess.text_1 = res.f;
    languageSess.title = 'a3boot';
    res.render('missPassword', languageSess)
});
```

Но почему-то node js рендерит только роутер, который прописан выше(в файле). Тоисть даже если вызывать /:missPass роутерит к /:actReg. Возможно это изза того что он види ":" и неважно что там дальше. Но как это пофиксить?

Comment: А что должно быть? `:` говорит что там дальше плейсхолдер - оба роута матчат одинаковые урлы, поэтому работает первый из них

Comment: покажите больше кода, по-моему у вас оба пути ведут в одно и тоже место!

Comment: @KirillStoianov @k 102 исправил. По сути он рендерят меня на одну html страницу. Но функционал на них разный

Comment: @ItsMyLife как заметили выше k102 я тоже думаю что проблема в урле, попробуйте  убрать двоеточие, хотя даже если вы уберете, я не совсем понимаю  почему у вас два варианта обработки одного и того же урла, или они с разными параметрами принимают запросы?

Comment: @KirillStoianov А как тогда создать 2 разных Url'a? Мне нужно что б при переходе на разные урлы обрабатывало разные событься

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> даже если вызывать `/:missPass` роутерит к `/:actReg`

Для примера, в строке `/:missPass` спрятано две сущности сразу:

- Шаблон `/*` для **совпадения** путевой части URL
  (имя переменной распознать из пути невозможно, его там просто нет)
- Шаблон `/`<kbd>missPass</kbd> для **разбора** путевой части на поля в запросе

Вот и получается, что у `/:actReg` и у `/:missPass` шаблоны для **совпадения** одинаковые: `/*`.

Как починить? Сделать правила так, чтобы шаблоны для совпадения были **разными**. Например, сделав опознавательные префиксы:

- `/actReg/:actReg`
- `/missPass/:missPass`

`/missPass/*` != `/actReg/*`, шаблоны для совпадения разные, победа.

Comment: Спасибо за информацию но вот так                                    /actReg/:actReg
/missPass/:missPass не работает. Я использовал предыдущий совет, Но немного модифицирован. В отделих файлах я создал роутеры и в app.js использовав app.use подключился к ним

Comment: @ItsMyLife значит, есть **ещё** какие-то проблемы, которые из текста вопроса я не могу выявить. Но эту устранить точно придётся.

Answer (score 1):

У вас уже есть два роута, например, `/:actReg` и  `/:missPass`, если у вас есть четыре разных метода которые должны обрабатыать 4 разных запроса, то вобще никаких проблем: делаете просто  `/missPass` и   `/missPass2` ,  `/actReg` и  `/actReg2` и просто перенаправляете потом в нужные методы для обработки. Если же вам принципиально что  бы все четыре варианта событий отрабатывали по двум урлам, можно сделать так:

посылаем `POST` запрос на урл `/actReg` и обрабатываем так:

**app.js**

```
var reg = require('./routes/reg');
app.use('/actReg', reg);
```

**./routes/reg.js**

```
router.post('/', function (req, res, next) {
  req.on('data', function (data) {
    body += data;

    var tag = body.tag;
    switch(tag){
        case "some_tag_1": function1(); break;
        case "some_tag_2": function2(); break;
    }
  });
});
```

Далее из тела запросы достаете параметр по которому определяете в какую фукцию передать запрос на обработку, и точно так же делаете для урла `/missPass`.

В итоге получаете что  по одному и тому же `url` вы можете отправлять запрос с разным содержимым, и в зависимости от содержимого - по-разному его обрабатывать.

Внутри **./routes/reg.js** можно можно еще разделить пути так

```
router.post('/myRoute1', function (req, res, next) {
  req.on('data', function (data) {
    body += data;
  }
}

router.post('/myRoute2', function (req, res, next) {
  req.on('data', function (data) {
    body += data;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

app.js

```
   app.use('/actReg:actReg', actReg);
    app.use('/missPassword:missPass', missPass);
```

Вот так кой вот рабочий ответ.
actReg.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
router.get('/',function(req, res, next) {
...
});
```

missPass.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
router.get('/',function(req, res, next) {
...
});
```